# Dynamic testing with AVA

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, ava

I'm looking to run ava programmaticaly, so my script would be able to run some ava tests with a dynamic argument (an URL actually).

My goal is to run programmaticaly the same ava test file on a list of dynamic (from user-input) URL, and then, get back the output.

I know the [ava api](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/api.js) is a good starting point, but I can see that the official [gulp-ava](https://github.com/avajs/gulp-ava/blob/master/index.js) don't use this API, and the API usage is not clear to me.

So, TL;DR :

- How can I run an ava test file from my own nodejs script ?
- How can I pass a dynamic argument to an ava test file, from my script ?
- How can I get back the output from AVA ?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official API you can use. The best approach would be to run AVA in a child process. The exit code will be `0` if tests pass.

Currently you can't pass command line arguments to the test workers. You should provide your URL through an environment variable.